# How do I make my application available on the App Store iPod 2G + iPhone3GS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

we are making an app which 
need to support `iPod Touch 2G` and more than `iPhone 3GS`.

Is that possible?

**EDIT**: I don't want to support `3G`.

Comment: It's not up to you what device you support. You should concentrate on what features your app needs. If a device does not have a feature you require, then your app won't be available for that device. You can set device requirements in the `info.plist`. Apple doesn't allow you to exclude on a per device basis. Also I believe the iPod Touch 2G uses the armv6 architecture which means as of Xcode 4.5, you can't compile your app to run on that device since Xcode 4.5 doesn't support compiling for armv6 anymore. So in short, you can't compile for anything lower then iPod Touch 4G, and < iPhone 3GS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3GS is not difficult to support; it's an armv7 processor, and can be targeted with Xcode 4.5. They'll run iOS 5 or even iOS 6. Aside from having more limited memory, they're not difficult to develop for at all.

The 2nd Generation iPod Touch (and the third generation, for that matter) are both equipped with an armv6 family processor.

- Xcode 4.5 can not generate code for the armv6. You'll need to use Xcode 4.4.1 or earlier to develop for them, and the compilers are not in good shape.
- They can not run iOS 5 or 6. In fact, they won't even run 4.3; you need to target 4.2.

The 3GS is a pretty reasonable requirement, but you should not target the older iPod touch models.

Comment: I dont't want to support 3G. Is that possible? I have updated the question.

Comment: If you build an armv7 application, it'll require an iPhone 3GS, 4th generation iPod touch, or iPad (any).